# Изменить вывод ширины и высоты у картинки

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

В контенте выводится текст и картинка вот таким образом

```
<img alt="" src="{{url}}" style="height:266px; width:400px">
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как через preg_replace изменить вывод у картинки чтобы вышло так:

```
<img alt="" src="{{url}}" height="266" width="400">
```

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: не нужно использовать регулярные выражения для манипуляций с html.

Comment: и почему бы не поменять это прямо в шаблоне?

Comment: @teran скорее всего там wysiwyg со своим самоваром

Comment: @norbornen, используется ckeditor

Comment: ну так пора включать голову https://www.google.ru/search?q=ckeditor+image+width+and+height+to+attributes&oq=ckeditor+image+width+and+height+to+attributes&aqs=chrome..69i57j0.12007j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

Такой пример:

```
$string = '<img alt="" src="{{url}}" style="height:266px; width:400px">';

echo preg_replace("/style.*(height):(\d+).*(width):(\d+).*\"/ui", '$1="$2" $3="$4"', $string);
```

Структура:

> *style="height:266px; width:400px"* **=>** *height="266" width="400"*

[DEMO](https://ideone.com/kaOoTa)